# How to: Update calendar events that were imported by iCalendar file?

Tags: icalendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ICalendar and event updates not working in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453/icalendar-and-event-updates-not-working-in-outlook)
>   [Help updating an event in Outlook 2007 with an iCalendar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275759/help-updating-an-event-in-outlook-2007-with-an-icalendar-file)

How do I update calendar events that were imported by iCalendar file?

I need to re-import events but I want to make sure that the existing events are updated. Currently if I do an import, it adds additional event instead of updating existing event on my Outlook calendar.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0        
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:123@mydomain.com
METHOD:REFRESH
CATEGORIES:MEETING
STATUS:TENTATIVE
DTSTART:20081125T233000Z
DTEND:20081125T233000Z
SUMMARY: Updated Event 2. Imported From iCalendar File.
DESCRIPTION:This is a test
CLASS:PRIVATE
END:VEVENT       
END:VCALENDAR
```

I'm trying to use METHOD: REFRESH I also tried METHOD: REQUEST but it still adds additional event instead of updating existing event on my Outlook calendar.

Comment: Similar problem on these stackoverflow questions: [ICalendar and event updates not working in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453/icalendar-and-event-updates-not-working-in-outlook) and [Help updating an event in Outlook 2007 with an iCalendar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275759/help-updating-an-event-in-outlook-2007-with-an-icalendar-file) I hope you can find the solution there.

Comment: How did you fixed your problem ?