# Generate icalendar file to update existing event

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I've created the following iCalendar file to generate the initial event

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:icalendar-ruby
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170529T184713Z
UID:call_286@foobar.dev
DTSTART:20170427T160000Z
DTEND:20170427T163000Z
DESCRIPTION:A test call
SEQUENCE:7
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:A test call
URL:http://foobar.dev/calls/286
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER:-PT15M
DESCRIPTION:Starting in 15 minutes - A test call
SUMMARY:A test call starting in 15 minutes
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This event is properly imported into OSX's Calendar (v 9.0) with all the correct details and Sync'd to Google Calendar.

I then update the event and generate an updated iCalendar file, keeping the `UID` the same and increment the `SEQUENCE` as per the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-141)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:icalendar-ruby
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170529T185549Z
UID:call_286@foobar.dev
DTSTART:20170427T153000Z
DTEND:20170427T155500Z
DESCRIPTION:A test call
SEQUENCE:8
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:A test call
URL:http://foobar.dev/calls/286
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER:-PT15M
DESCRIPTION:Starting in 15 minutes - A test call
SUMMARY:A test call starting in 15 minutes
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I then import this event into OSX's Calendar and my original event disappears from the calendar completely. It doesn't update at all just completely disappears.

When I look at Google Calendar the original event is still there in the exactly the same place as per the initial time schedule.

What am I doing wrong that the event is not updating?

**Update:** This question is not a duplicate of [Update an event in Outlook 2007 with an iCalendar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275759/update-an-event-in-outlook-2007-with-an-icalendar-file) or [ICalendar and event updates not working in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453/icalendar-and-event-updates-not-working-in-outlook) or [Update an event in Outlook 2007 with an iCalendar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275759/update-an-event-in-outlook-2007-with-an-icalendar-file) as this question related to **OSX's Calendar (v 9.0) application** and subsequent syncing with **Google Calendar** and **not Outlook**. I have tried the approaches described in answers to those questions but I get exactly the same behaviour as described above.

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using to perform the update/view the calendar? This could be anything from a syntax issue, to cacheing, to a network error, to permission settings, to .... ? We always request that a [Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) be provided in the question, if possible.

Comment: @TomLord I don't think I fully understand your point. I simply save the above as an `.ics` file and then double click it to install it into iCalendar. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What has this got to do with `ruby`, or `ruby-on-rails`, if your question makes no mention of these? That's why I'm confused.

Comment: @TomLord Apologies, now I understand your question. I am using the [iCalendar gem](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar) to generate the ICS files.

Comment: Ahh ok, fair enough. A quick google search found me this [possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45969/1954610) -- do you need to specify `METHOD:REQUEST` instead of `METHOD:PUBLISH`?

Comment: As stated above I'm working with OSX's Calendar and Google Calendar, not Outlook as specified in that question. When I try that approach I get an error from OSX's Calendar telling me that has not been able to write to Google Calendar.

Comment: It was just a shot in the dark, I have no idea sorry. I feel this question might be better suited to `ServerFault` since it doesn't seem to actually relate to code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to: Update calendar events that were imported by iCalendar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314937/how-to-update-calendar-events-that-were-imported-by-icalendar-file)

Comment: Duplicate question on StackOverflow: [ical file refference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453/icalendar-and-event-updates-not-working-in-outlook) and [ical file refferece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275759/update-an-event-in-outlook-2007-with-an-icalendar-file)