# Calendar event are not changing/cancelling using ics file

Tags: php, icalendar, coldfusion-11

I am dealing with ics files and I am new in it. Actually I am sending an event through email and also sending an ics file as even. The problem is that I am sending appointment confirmation using ics and user saves or adds it in calendar. But if later on user requests to cancel the appointment  then another mail is sent having ics file. 
If the user saves that file in calendar then the file should be replaced in calendar. Is this possible? If so then how can i do that. 
I am sending the appointment confirmation using following file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//AddEvent.com v1.6//ENX-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York
Method: REQUEST         -- mandatory for Outlook
BEGIN:VEVENT
TIMEZONE:America/New_York
DTSTAMP:20180430T104326Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
UID:20183010432643447356
DTSTART:20181125T083000Z
DTEND:20181125T090000Z
SUMMARY:Appointment Details - Center for Vein Restoration 
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html::Appointment Details Center for Vein Restoration 
LOCATION:4900 Seminary Road, Suit 100 Alexandria, VA 222234
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
ORGANIZER;CN="GuestServices@example.com":mailto:GuestServices@example.com
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:vijaykaturu@gmail.com
END:VALARM
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And the file that has cancellation confirmation that is following

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//AddEvent.com v1.6//ENX-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York
Method: CANCEL  
BEGIN:VEVENT
TIMEZONE:America/New_York
DTSTAMP:20180430T104326Z
STATUS:CANCELLED
UID:20183010432643447356
DTSTART:20181125T083000Z
DTEND:20181125T090000Z
SUMMARY:Appointment Details - Cancel Center for Vein Restoration 
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html::Appointment Details Center for Vein Restoration 
LOCATION:4900 Seminary Road, Suit 100 Alexandria, VA 222234
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The problem is that it saves another event in calendar instead of replacing or cancelling

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453/icalendar-and-event-updates-not-working-in-outlook

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?