# ICalendar with Spatie/ICalendar-Generator creating new meetings rather than updating in Outlook

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, icalendar

After taking a look through the following [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453/icalendar-and-event-updates-not-working-in-outlook) I added some additional fields and remove some current fields inside the ICS file.

My invitation renders like so:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:spatie/icalendar-generator
NAME:Test ICS 2
X-WR-CALNAME:Test ICS 2
DESCRIPTION:Test ICS 2
X-WR-CALDESC:Test ICS 2
X-WR-RELCALID:someConstValue.ba7be5f8-7404-4bf8-bfe6-80c17e9ade76
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/London
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20211031T020000Z
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20220327T010000Z
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20221030T020000Z
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:UTC
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20211028T100304Z
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:someConstValue.ba7be5f8-7404-4bf8-bfe6-80c17e9ade76
DTSTAMP:20220725T100304Z
SUMMARY:Test ICS 2
DESCRIPTION:Test ICS 2
LOCATION:TRUNCATED
CLASS:PRIVATE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN=TRUNCATED
ATTENDEE;CN=TRUNCATED
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20220725T140000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20220725T143000
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Test ICS 2 is going to start in 15 minutes.
TRIGGER:-PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I now want to update the time, so I resend an update ICS like so:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:spatie/icalendar-generator
NAME:Test ICS 2
DESCRIPTION:Test ICS 2
X-WR-CALDESC:Test ICS 2
X-WR-RELCALID:someConstValue.ba7be5f8-7404-4bf8-bfe6-80c17e9ade76
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/London
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20211031T020000Z
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20220327T010000Z
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20221030T020000Z
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:UTC
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20211028T100354Z
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:someConstValue.ba7be5f8-7404-4bf8-bfe6-80c17e9ade76
DTSTAMP:20220725T100354Z
SUMMARY:Test ICS 2
DESCRIPTION:Test ICS 2
LOCATION:TRUNCATED
CLASS:PRIVATE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
ORGANIZER;CN=TRUNCATED
ATTENDEE;CN=TRUNCATED
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20220725T140500
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20220725T143000
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Test ICS 2 is going to start in 15 minutes.
TRIGGER:-PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I added `X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN`, `X-WR-RELCALID` and removed `X-WR-CALNAME` when sending updates as the previous SO threads explain but this still generates a new event in Outlook as apposed to updating the current one.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to what I am missing?

Comment: How to know which event will be updated or not? I think there is unique value, you have to pass like id.

Comment: Both `X-WR-RELCALID` and `UID` are unique for each meeting (they are the same as each other for each meeting because other mail systems use `UID`), when sending an update, I recall this unique ID and use it. The `constantValue` is just my app name prefixed before the UUID so I don't (on the off-chance) collide with another event that doesn't come from our app. @RBC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see in the linked original SO question, a value is required for the `METHOD` field, which you are currently missing, to be able to update the invitation in Outlook

> In summary you have to specify
> `METHOD:REQUEST` and `ORGANIZER:xxxxxxxx`
> in addition to `UID:` and `SEQUENCE:`

Comment: I spent too long getting frustrated at this and completely missed this. Adding a SEQUENCE and METHOD:REQUEST worked. For future viewers, the SEQUENCE I created as `0` for initial invites, then incremented each other after. Thanls!